# Making delegate methods not visible for other classes

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have 2 classes,

`class A`(Obj-C) and

`class B`(Swift).

Class A has a delegate protocol

```
@protocol ADelegate<NSObject>

- (void)someMethod:(NSString *)str;

@end
```

to which class B conforms:

`class B: ADelegate { ... }`

But the issue is, the other Objective-C classes which use `class B` as a property can access to those delegate methods to which my Swift class conforms. For example, there is a `class C`(Obj-C):

```
@interface Class_C_ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) B *classB_property;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.classB_property someMethod: @""];
}

@end
```

So basically that Swift property can access and call the delegate methods from another Obj-C class.
Is there a way to make those methods private, so no other class can call those methods but Swift class?

I really hope that I could explain my issue. If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Hi, @OlSen and thanks for your reply! I need those methods in protocol as they are delegate methods. But I do not want to access them through the property

Comment: @OlSen is there any way around? Maybe wrappers or something? =/

Comment: a classic delegate is just a weak pointer `@property (__weak) id<Protocol>` with protocol informations. It can even point to its own property holding class object which does not make much sense but it's possible.

Comment: still not really sure what you want to achieve. You want an objc class thats own methods can be only accessed from swift?

Comment: @OlSen no, I want that other ObjC classes stop seeing/calling my delegate methods. So they should not be able to call like that `[self.classB_property someMethod: @""];`

Comment: Just conform protocol privately in `classB` extension in `.m` file

Comment: @Cy-4AH no, please read the question again. I have a Swift class property in my ObjC ViewController and **it** accesses the delegate methods because the Swift class conforms to that delegate protocol

Comment: Then conform to protocol privately in `classB` extension in `.swift` file ‍♂️

Comment: @Cy-4AH how can I do that? I'm already conforming from `extension`

Comment: Yes, sorry, private protocol conformance is big illness of swift :( `'private' modifier cannot be used with extensions that declare protocol conformances`

Comment: There is nothing you can do about this. There is nothing special about the delegate function; it is just a function of class B. There is nothing stopping you from calling any delegate function on any class in Objective C or Swift aside from the convention that delegate functions should only be called by the delegating object.